# How to overwrite parameter of Data Factory in Azure DevOps Pipeline? - Empty space in ARM Template cause errors?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to add parameter in Azure Data Factory so that I can overwrite parameter value for each Dev, Test and Prod environment. Currently I have set static string in DevOps Release as parameter value.

However I get strange errors from Azure DevOps.
I wonder why Data Factory save parameter name as "Web pipeline_properties_parameters_LogicAppURL_defaultValue", which has empty space after Web.

1. Have edited "ARM Template"->"Edit parameter configuration" and published parameter:

   "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {
   "properties": {
   "parameters": {
   "LogicAppURL": {
   "defaultValue": "="
   }
   }
   }
2. ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json in Git Repo:

   ```
    {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "factoryName": {
            "value": "my-warehouse-dev-df"
        },
        "Web pipeline_properties_parameters_LogicAppURL_defaultValue": {
            "value": "http://www.devpipeline.fi"
        }
    }
   ```

   }

Error when creating release:

```
  The detected encoding for file 'D:\a\r1\a\_Azure Data 
  Factory DevOps-CI\drop\ARMTemplateForFactory.json' is 'utf-8'
  
  The detected encoding for file 'D:\a\r1\a\_Azure Data 
  Factory DevOps-CI\drop\ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json' is 'utf-8'
  
  There was an error while overriding 'Web' parameter 
  because of 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined', make sure it 
  follows JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
  
  There was an error while overriding '' parameter 
  because of 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined', make sure it 
  follows 
  JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
  
  Starting template validation.
  Deployment name is ARMTemplateForFactory-20211220-162118-0e5d

  There were errors in your deployment. Error code: 
  InvalidDeploymentParameterKey.
  ##[error]One of the deployment parameters has an empty 
  key. Please see https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. As the error says, try to edit the parameter name as below.

However, placing it between `" "` should have sufficed.

```
"Web_pipeline_properties_parameters_LogicAppURL_defaultValue"
```

Also, if you would want to leave the parameter value empty by default, you can set as below:

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "LogicAppURL": {
                "defaultValue": {}
            }
        }
    }
```

And while overriding template parameter, use:

```
-param "value"
```

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me:

on the data factory tab go to Manage>ARM templates> Include global parameters in ARM template. Add any parameter that isn't already parametrised to the arm-template-parameters-definition.json file. Add the arm-template-parameters-definition.json file to your devops repository where the data factory artifacts are.

When deploying to different environments, use

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ variables.service_connection }}
    KeyVaultName: ${{ variables.kv_name }}
    SecretsFilter: 'exampleValue,anotherValue'
  displayName: 'get environment-specific secrets'

- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
      inputs:
        azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ variables.service_connection }}
        subscriptionId: $(SubscriptionId)
        location: ${{ variables.location }}
        templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
        csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
 csmParametersFile:'$(Pipeline.Workspace)/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
        overrideParameters: '
        -example_properties_typeProperties_value $(exampleValue)
        -another_properties_typeProperties_value $(anotherValue)
        -factoryName "${{ variables.factory_name }}"'
        deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

Comment: The navigation instructions would be easier to read if you: use spaces around the arrows, and use actual arrows (→), and make the step names italic or bold, so readers know precisely what labels or whatever to search for.