# 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined', make sure it follows JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault, securestring

My initial code was :

```
{
    "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/MemoExtraction')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
    "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureFunction",
        "typeProperties": {
            "functionAppUrl": "[parameters('MemoExtraction_properties_typeProperties_functionAppUrl')]",
            "functionKey": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "[parameters('MemoExtraction_functionKey')]"
                                                        
                                                    
                  
                                       
            },
            "authentication": "Anonymous"
        }
    },
    "dependsOn": []
                                                                              
     
},
```

I have pushed new code as:

```
{
    "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/MemoExtraction')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
    "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureFunction",
        "typeProperties": {
            "functionAppUrl": "[parameters('MemoExtraction_properties_typeProperties_functionAppUrl')]",
            "functionKey": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                    "referenceName": "Ls_AzureKeyVault",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": "MemoKey"
            },
            "authentication": "Anonymous"
        }
    },
    "dependsOn": [
       "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/linkedServices/Ls_AzureKeyVault')]"
    ]
},
```

I am getting the below error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lofy.png)

I am not sure why I am getting this error while deployment. It should deploy successfully .

Answer (score 0):

I created one Function Linked Service with Key vault and then exported the ARM template of my ADF like below:-

[image]

Exported the template of the above ADF pipeline with ADF resource like below:-

[image]

From the Exported ARM code file, I selected the below 2 codes and replaced the Data factory parameter to the new ADF name without any pipeline, For the Azure Function Linked service to get deployed in the new ADF pipeline like below:-

**Exported ARM code:-**

[image]

Added the above two files in my Azure repository and replaced the ADF name parameter with the new **testadf90silicon** name like below:-

**ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json**

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "factoryName": {
            "value": "testadf90silicon"
        },
        "AzureKeyVault1_properties_typeProperties_baseUrl": {
            "value": "https://siliconkeyvault90.vault.azure.net/"
        },
        "AzureFunction1_properties_typeProperties_functionAppUrl": {
            "value": "https://siliconfunc65.azurewebsites.net"
        }
    }
}
```

**ARMTemplateForFactory.json**

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "factoryName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": "Data Factory name",
            "defaultValue": "testadf90silicon"
        },
        "AzureKeyVault1_properties_typeProperties_baseUrl": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "https://siliconkeyvault90.vault.azure.net/"
        },
        "AzureFunction1_properties_typeProperties_functionAppUrl": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "https://siliconfunc65.azurewebsites.net"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "factoryId": "[concat('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', parameters('factoryName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/pipeline1')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Azure Function1",
                        "type": "AzureFunctionActivity",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "functionName": "siliconfunc65",
                            "method": "GET",
                            "headers": {}
                        },
                        "linkedServiceName": {
                            "referenceName": "AzureFunction1",
                            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "elapsedTimeMetric": {},
                    "cancelAfter": {}
                },
                "annotations": []
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/linkedServices/AzureFunction1')]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/AzureKeyVault1')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "annotations": [],
                "type": "AzureKeyVault",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "baseUrl": "[parameters('AzureKeyVault1_properties_typeProperties_baseUrl')]"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/AzureFunction1')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "annotations": [],
                "type": "AzureFunction",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "functionAppUrl": "[parameters('AzureFunction1_properties_typeProperties_functionAppUrl')]",
                    "functionKey": {
                        "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                        "store": {
                            "referenceName": "AzureKeyVault1",
                            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                        },
                        "secretName": "secret",
                        "secretVersion": "cf004fc9796f40d1867c3647b76de797"
                    },
                    "authentication": "Anonymous"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/linkedServices/AzureKeyVault1')]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:-**

*Azure Function Linked Service Pipeline got created in new ADF:-*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also refer this similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70425176/how-to-overwrite-parameter-of-data-factory-in-azure-devops-pipeline-empty-spa) by KarthikBhyresh-MT where you can override parameter for your function key and URI values.